# How can I force a pdf file to be on the same page as its title?

Tags: pdfpages

When I insert my pdf file the title is on one page and the file on the next pages (multiple-sided pdf file). How can I force the first page of the pdf file to be on the same page as the title?

I have tried following:

```
\begin{figure}
\section{TITEL}
    \includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.8]{Myfile.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

By doing this I only get one page of the pdf file (but together with the title). Then I tried:

```
\section{TITEL}
\vspace{-20mm}
    \includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.8]{Myfile.pdf}
```

And nothing happens.

Is there someone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Include the first page with `\includegraphics{Myfile.pdf}` instead. And for the rest use `\includepdf[pages={2-}]{Myfile.pdf}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved in the comments, by loading the first page with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik why not post an answer?

Comment: @DaiBowen My comment was more a workaround than a solution... But I made an appropriate answer as you asked :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, if it's only a workaround then I see even less reason to rush to close the question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, because the close message says the question is off-topic and that “This question does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems as defined in the help center” which is definitely *not* true. It gives a misleading idea to anyone who sees this question, that such questions are not welcome here, when the opposite is the case. The fact that the “issue was solved in the comments” is not a valid reason for closing a question.

Answer (score 5):

As requested :)

The `\includepdf` command always creates a new page, so you cannot (lie!) put an included pdf in the same page as something else.

But you can use `\includegraphics` to place the first page of the pdf in the same page as the `\section`:

```
\section{Title}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Myfile.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2-},scale=0.8]{Myfile.pdf}
```

Or you can use the `pagecommand` of `\includepdf`:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.8,pagecommand={\section{Title}}]{Myfile.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2-},scale=0.8]{Myfile.pdf}
```

Either way, you'll have to separate the first page from the rest.

If you are going to include several files this way, you can define a command:

```
\newcommand{\includepdfwithsection}[3][]{%
  \def\incpdfopts{#1}%
  \expandafter\includepdf\expandafter[\incpdfopts,pages=1,pagecommand={\section{#2}}]{#3}%
  \expandafter\includepdf\expandafter[\incpdfopts,pages={2-}]{TCC.pdf}%
}
```

and use it as:

```
\includepdfwithsection[<options>]{<Section Title>}{<PDF File>}
```

for example:

```
\includepdfwithsection[scale=0.8]{Title}{Myfile.pdf}
```

and the result will be the same as above.